# How to style sheet with format "number: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5"?

Tags: css

```
<ul>
    <li>number</li> 
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

And style sheet:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none
}

ul li {
    float: left;
}

li:after {
    content: ", "
}

li:before {
    content: ": "
}

li:last-child:after {
    content: "."
}

li:first-child:before {
    content: ""
}
```

Result is:

```
number, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
```

How to fix to this result:

```
number: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
```

Comment: The result in your question is not the actual result of the CSS in your question. This makes it hard to answer it correctly.

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twH8W/)

Answer (score 7):

Add this:

```
li:first-child:after {
    content: ": "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with  `li:first-child:after {content: ": "}` too add : after number line
And `li:not(:first-child):after {content: ", "}` too add , after any other line

complete solution

```
ul {list-style-type: none}
ul li {float: left;}
li:not(:first-child):after {content: ", "}
li:last-child:after {content: "."}
li:first-child:after {content: ": "}
```

You can check the dabblet gist : http://dabblet.com/gist/4681763